# openNtf debugToolbar UI is overridden by extLib's Bootstrap3 theme

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

This relates to an Xpages project using openNtf's Extension Library for Domino 9.0.1 V 16 (2016-01-28). There is a custom theme applied that extends extLib's Bootstrap3 theme. 
Now I also applied Mark Leusink's debugToolbar Plugin (V 4.0.1, 2014-03-10).
Unfortunately all tables that are display inside the toolbar are partially "destroyed", as in this example:

[image]

Debugging the resulting html I see that the "label" cells of the debug table are assigned `class="label"` or `class="label wide"`. Unfortunately `bootstrap.css` applies a `display: inline` style to a `.label` selector.

Currently I solved this by applying my own custom css file to reset toolbar styling; but I wonder whether there might be a more elegant way, maybe some kind of property that I simply missed out here. Or is this something that have to be done within the toolbar's source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully Paul's and my entries at github and within the openntf.org project will help resolving this issue. Meanwhile my workaround seems to be the only option here;

As I mentioned above I created a custom styleSheet with just one line in it:

```
div.dBar table.grid td.label{display:table-cell;}
```

Then I created a cusom control as a container for the debug toolbar so that I could link my custom style sheet as a resource. The debug custom control finally is added to all the xpages where I want to have the toolbar.

Maybe this can help others, too.

Answer (score 3):

Please add this as a defect on the project, so the contributor is aware and can resolve.

Alternatively, download the source code from https://github.com/OpenNTF/DebugToolbar, contribute the fix and make a pull request.

Comment: I did post it as a discussion topic; no access rights to the github, so no way for me to add it as a defect

Comment: No problem, I've logged it there https://github.com/OpenNTF/DebugToolbar/issues/10. I probably won't get time to look at it for a few weeks, but hopefully someone else will create a pull request, if Mark doesn't have time.

Comment: many thanks (it should probably say "debugToolbar table's label class overridden by bootstrap UI" or something like that, but it's explained here, so never mind)